# Decode base64 URL and embedding in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, cookies, base64

I want make like this http://www.jredtna.com/read/?hash=cGxheWVyIDEgPT4gaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cueW91dHViZS5jb20vZW1iZWQvZmgwUUQtV1dyY2MKcGxheWVyIDIgPT4gaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cueW91dHViZS5jb20vZW1iZWQvMk1wVWotQXVhNDg=

(You can't see iframe because website using cookies to check if you coming from another website).

So please join here http://halqat.online/video/watch.php?vid=6f673f4c5 and click red play button to see what I mean.

When decode hash= by base64:

> cGxheWVyIDEgPT4gaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cueW91dHViZS5jb20vZW1iZWQvZmgwUUQtV1dyY2MKcGxheWVyIDIgPT4gaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cueW91dHViZS5jb20vZW1iZWQvMk1wVWotQXVhNDg=

will give us like this:

> player 1 => https://www.youtube.com/embed/fh0QD-WWrcc
>
> player 2 => https://www.youtube.com/embed/2MpUj-Aua48

My question is how I can do like that:

Get **hash=Base64URL**

Decode it and split "**player 1**" and "**youtube url**" by **=>**

Put data inside html like this

```
<div class="embeding">
  <ul>
      <li><a data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fh0QD-WWrcc">player 1</a></li>
      <li><a data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2MpUj-Aua48">player 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and auto add **li a** if find another players

Comment: Please take a few minutes to read [ask] then edit question with a properly detailed  and self contained written explanation of your problem. Hard to make much sense out of all of this

Comment: sorry about that, but my english so bad, please only read my question and will understand because i'm explained everything

Comment: Well perhaps someone else will understand... i sure don't

Comment: thank you anyway, if you want help me, i can give you my email to contact with us, and will explain more to you by images or video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use splice method to make an array and then from this array I get the youtube url's strings via split method.

```js
function decodeBase_64(arg){ 
  var decodedData=window.atob(arg);
  var a;
  var c=[];  
  for(var i=0;i<decodedData.split('=>').length;i++){
    if(decodedData.split('=>')[i].length>10){      
      a=decodedData.split('=>')[i];
      a=a.substr(0, 42);
      c.push(a);
    }
  }
   return c; 
}
document.getElementById('player_1').setAttribute('data-src',decodeBase_64('cGxheWVyIDEgPT4gaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cueW91dHViZS5jb20vZW1iZWQvZmgwUUQtV1dyY2MKcGxheWVyIDIgPT4gaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cueW91dHViZS5jb20vZW1iZWQvMk1wVWotQXVhNDg=')[0] );
document.getElementById('player_2').setAttribute('data-src',decodeBase_64('cGxheWVyIDEgPT4gaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cueW91dHViZS5jb20vZW1iZWQvZmgwUUQtV1dyY2MKcGxheWVyIDIgPT4gaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cueW91dHViZS5jb20vZW1iZWQvMk1wVWotQXVhNDg=')[1] );

console.log(decodeBase_64('cGxheWVyIDEgPT4gaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cueW91dHViZS5jb20vZW1iZWQvZmgwUUQtV1dyY2MKcGxheWVyIDIgPT4gaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cueW91dHViZS5jb20vZW1iZWQvMk1wVWotQXVhNDg='));
console.log(decodeBase_64('cGxheWVyIDEgPT4gaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cueW91dHViZS5jb20vZW1iZWQvZmgwUUQtV1dyY2MKcGxheWVyIDIgPT4gaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cueW91dHViZS5jb20vZW1iZWQvMk1wVWotQXVhNDg=')[0]);
console.log(decodeBase_64('cGxheWVyIDEgPT4gaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cueW91dHViZS5jb20vZW1iZWQvZmgwUUQtV1dyY2MKcGxheWVyIDIgPT4gaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cueW91dHViZS5jb20vZW1iZWQvMk1wVWotQXVhNDg=')[1]);
```

```html
<div class="embeding">
  <ul>
      <li><a data-src="" id="player_1">player 1</a></li>
      <li><a data-src="" id="player_2">player 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Check the console to see the c array

For the second issue..Get the her via window.location.href and then

```js
var str='http://www.jredtna.com/read/?hash=cGxheWVyIDEgPT4gaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cueW91dHViZS5jb20vZW1iZWQvZmgwUUQtV1dyY2MKcGxheWVyIDIgPT4gaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cueW91dHViZS5jb20vZW1iZWQvMk1wVWotQXVhNDg=';
str=str.substring(str.indexOf("hash="));
str=str.replace('hash=','');
console.log(str);
```

Comment: thank you very much, but base64 code is variable,


you can add window.location or something to let code get base64 from URL automatically after ?hash=


another issue, you add only player1 and player2 to code, if i added player3 in base64 url, this will not showing in html, you can make detect how much players i have in url automatically ?


example : if find 1 player, will add only one <li><a if find 4 players will add 4 <li><a etc


thank you again for this great work

Comment: For the first issue you can use decodeBase_64(base64).

Comment: thank you sir, but maybe you not read my another issue,
i want js code get variable base64 from url like this (http://website.com/show/?hash=cGxheWVyIDEgPT4gaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cueW91dHViZS5) ,
i really appreciate your effort with me, so if you can tell me your facebook or email or something to contact with you and explain more i will be grateful to you

Comment: thank you sir, now i can get base64 by url,
but i have another issues; if you can help me more i'll tell you what i need

Comment: You get the string url (str)  then you pass it into decodeBase_64() function as arg and that's it

Comment: i have other issues sir, like `a=a.substr(0, 42);` because my url is variable and not 42 words everytime and i want get before => too because player 1 and player 2 etc is variable too and not `length>10` everytime, and if can detect line break, so every return to line is a player

Comment: You can set 41 instead of 10.Do you have variable greater than 41 chars?

Comment: yes sir, url and player name is variable so not every time is 42 chars
i maked new question and you can answer me here
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49741481)